# using IF and else in Where clause and using IN ( in where condition field)

Tags: sql-server-2005

I want to run the following query. `@city` value will be provided run time

```
Select * from Emp
    where empno in (
        if( @city = 'Bangalore')
            Begin
                Select Empno from Emp
                    where EmpCity = @city
            End
        Else
            Begin
                Select empno from Emp
        End
    )
```

Kindly help me by providing alternative

Comment: you mean to say that when city is `Banglore` get the data based upon city , else get the total data.
this query alone will work fine
`if( @city = 'Bangalore') Begin Select Empno from Emp where EmpCity = @city End Else Begin Select empno from Emp End`

Comment: Actually I need to get the emp data based on different variables. In the above example I have mentioned only one variable. If it is more than one variable then using the outline if & else will be bit difficult. Is there any other alternative for using IN with IF where condition?

Comment: Do all of these conditions continue to only select rows from the original `Emp` table? Can you add a few more examples - single examples tend to not expose all of the required detail.

Comment: Let me explain in this way...

I want the emp data based on follwoing conditions:

1) EmpCity should be either 'Bangalore' or it should be all the city's

and 

2) EmpSalary should be 10000 or it should include all the salaries available in the table.

and 

3) Emp_Designation should be 'PM' or it should include all the designations.

like this I have to satisfy different conditions. I want to get the empno based on above conditions so that the outer query will get the emp data based on the EMpno ( Empno from where clause).

Comment: But if all of these conditions are based on columns within the `Emp` table, why introduce this `IN()` expression at all - why not just write them as conditions in the `WHERE` clause of the outer query (and scrap the inner query)? I've updated my query with these conditions.

Answer (score 1):

`IF` is a control flow *statement*. You can't place statements inside other statements.

The usual thing people are looking for when they come up with `IF` is [`CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx), which is an *expression*. However, in this case, a far simpler query seems doable:

```
Select * from Emp
where
    (EmpCity = @city or @city != 'Bangalore') and
    (EmpSalary = @salary or @salary != 20000) and
    (Designation = @designation or @designation != 'PM')
```

I don't see why you have the nested select at all

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot for your help. Let me try changing the actual logic of my query. I will get back to you if I need your help.

Comment: I want the condition for Empcity = @City or Empcity = all the cities.

Comment: @VenkateswarluAvula - the condition will be true if `Empcity = @City and @city = 'bangalore'`. And it will also be true if `@city` isn't equal to `'Bangalore'` (in which case, `EmpCity` can take any value) - which are the same conditions as in your question.

Answer (score 1):

suppose your search is based upon `EmpId` -- `@EmpId` and `City` -- `@city`

```
Select * 
from 
  Emp 
where 
 (@city  = '' or EmpCity = @city) and
 (@EmpId = '' or EmpId = @EmpId)
```